# Can the AUC of the ROC be interpreted as the average recall?

Tags: roc, auc, precision-recall

The PR curve plots the precision as a function of the recall, and the AUC can be interpreted as the average precision.
The ROC plots the recall as a function of the specificity. Can we interpret the AUC as the average recall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not usefully.

It's the recall integrated with equal weight over all possible specificities. That's not typically an average over any well-motivated real or imaginary distribution.

Comment: How is it different from interpreting the AUC ROC as the average precision?

Comment: @usual-me When you compute an "average" of a function $f$ that depends on a random variable $X$, you must compute the *expectation value* of $f$ as $\int f(x)\,p(x)\,dx$, where $p$ is the probability density of $X$. You want to replace $p(x)$ with $1/W$, where $W$ is the width of the interval over which the integration runs ($W=1$ in this particular case) which does not make much sense. This is what Thomas Lumley wanted to say in his answer.